# Line up table columns using *ngFor

Tags: angular

```
let readings = {
    "date" : "2017-07-09",
    "reading" : [
        { "meal" : "Breakfast" },
        { "meal" : "Lunch" },
        { "meal" : "Dinner" },
        { "meal" : "Supper" }
    ]
}
{
    "date" : "2017-07-10",
    "reading" : [
        { "meal" : "Lunch" },
        { "meal" : "Dinner" },
        { "meal" : "Supper" }
    ]
}
{
    "date" : "2017-07-11",
    "reading" : [
        { "meal" : "Breakfast" },
        { "meal" : "Lunch" }
    ]
}
```

Given the above `JSON`, can anybody advise the most elegant way to ensure all the columns line up in the table below? As you can see, there is a column for each meal but not every object contains every meal.

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Breakfast</th>
        <th>Lunch</th>
        <th>Dinner</th>
        <th>Supper</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let reading of readings">
        <td *ngFor="let item of reading.meal">Yes</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, guys. Here is the custom pipe I went with. What do you think?

```
@Pipe({ name: 'readings' })
export class ReadingsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(readings: any): any {
      return meals.map(meal => readings.find(reading => reading.meal === meal.meal));
    }
}

let meals = [
    { "meal" : "Breakfast"},
    { "meal" : "Lunch" },
    { "meal" : "Dinner" },
    { "meal" : "Supper" }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not do this without changing your json. You can try this way if you want to. change your json to this format.

```
{
    "date" : "2017-07-10",
    "reading" : {
        "Lunch" : "meal_name",
        "Dinner" : "meal_name",
        "Supper" : "meal_name"
    }
}
```

and change you table to this

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Breakfast</th>
        <th>Lunch</th>
        <th>Dinner</th>
        <th>Supper</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let read of readings">
        <td>{{ read.reading.Breakfast ? 'yes' : 'no'}}</td>
        <td>{{ read.reading.Lunch ? 'yes' : 'no'}}</td>
        <td>{{ read.reading.Dinner ? 'yes' : 'no'}}</td>
        <td>{{ read.reading.Supper ? 'yes' : 'no'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

i hope this will help :)

Comment: ThinkingMedia ya! we can use pipe also to modify json